# I'm getting a FormatException even though my C# code parses correctly

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, entities, formatexception

I have a line of code that runs as a part of my Save button. The Save button stores some data into my database. Part of the data that gets saved is each item's rank. I assign each item a rank in the front end and it gets parsed out and stored into the database. Here is the problematic code:

```
using(CCGEntities db = new CCGEntities())
{
    foreach(DataGridItem dgi in uxCustomSetList.Items)
    {
        int dataKey = (int)uxCustomSetList.DataKeys[dgi.ItemIndex];
        var temp = db.CustomSetAwardSets.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CustomSetAwardSetID == dataKey);
        temp.AwardSetComments = ((TextBox)dgi.FindControl("txtComments")).Text.Trim();
        temp.Rank =  Int32.Parse(((TextBox)dgi.FindControl("txtRank")).Text);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The problem is this line:

```
temp.Rank = Int32.Parse(((TextBox)dgi.FindControl("txtRank")).Text);
```

The rank for each item is saved into the database successfully but I'll get a FormatException error screen all the same. Any ideas what the problem is? The parsing is obviously working correctly if the data is being stored into the database, so why is it complaining about bad formatting? temp.Rank is an int? by the way.

Comment: have you put the content of txtRank into some log to see if it should actually throw exception. Are you sure you are not saving changes in another location?

Comment: I have not put the content of txtRank into some log to see if it should throw the exception, but seeing that the results are in the database suggests that it shouldn't be throwing an exception. Otherwise my table wouldn't have the values I entered. And I'm pretty sure changes aren't being saved elsewhere.

Comment: I suggest replacing that Parse with TryParse, and also share the StachTrace with us

Comment: There is nothing special in that code,so problem must be somewhere else

Comment: I will try TryParse. Would the problem be coming from trying to save some items with no rank? So in other words, would doing Int32.Parse on an empty string be the problem? Some items might not get any rank, in which case it would attempt to parse an empty string.

Comment: @HandleThatError: why don't you try and see what happens when `int.Parse("")` or `int.Parse(null)`, hmm? that's like, maybe, 1 minute to test it?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I was leaving for the day but I decided to pull up Visual Studio and give it a try, and yeah, it's because Int32.Parse("") throws the exception. :) Next time I'll try it before I ask lol

Comment: make rank integer value type as nullable. just like Int32? Rank;

Comment: @HandleThatError that is why I suggested sharing the stack-trace. To make sure exception is actually happening on that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, and especially when using input from a UI, using `TryParse` is a better idea than using `Parse`, as it is cleaner to check for errors (in my opinion) and gives the programmer a greater level of control over different possible input values.

Your specific error is probably because the text property of your control is empty or `null`, and this would throw a FormatError exception on an `int.Parse` call.